# How to see added open62541 parameters in uaexpert?

Tags: c, opc-ua, open62541

I'm posting this here because I'm convinced this is not a bug an it is just my test configuration that is not properly setup but I'm not able to put a finger on what I'm doing wrong.

I install the single file release:
https://open62541.org/releases/

along with the build environment for open62541 and then build and run this tutorial:
https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/master/examples/tutorial_server_variable.c

Using these commands:

```
gcc -std=c99 open62541.c myServerTuturial.c -o myServerTuturial
./myServerTuturial
```

But when I connect with UA expert with the anonymous login I'm not able to see any of the added variables per the example. I do see and am able to subscribe to several of the default server parameters. Greatly appreciate anyone that can explain why I'm not seeing the variables. I believe they should appear under the "Objects" folder in the left pane navigator.
[image: ua expert screenshot]
ua expert is version 1.4.4 275

Here is the server's console output:

```
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.091 (UTC-0700)] warn/server    AccessControl: Unconfigured 
AccessControl. Users have all permissions.
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.091 (UTC-0700)] info/server    AccessControl: Anonymous login is enabled
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.091 (UTC-0700)] warn/server    Username/Password configured, but no encrypting SecurityPolicy. This can leak credentials on the network.
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.091 (UTC-0700)] warn/userland  AcceptAll Certificate Verification. Any remote certificate will be accepted.
Writing a string returned statuscode BadNodeIdUnknown
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.091 (UTC-0700)] info/network   TCP network layer listening on opc.tcp://jchan-Z170N:4840/
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.328 (UTC-0700)] info/network   Connection 5 | New connection over TCP from 127.0.0.1
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.328 (UTC-0700)] info/channel   Connection 5 | SecureChannel 1 | SecureChannel opened with SecurityPolicy http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None and a revised lifetime of 600.00s
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.329 (UTC-0700)] warn/channel   Connection 5 | SecureChannel 1 | ActivateSession: Session not found
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.330 (UTC-0700)] info/channel   Connection 5 | SecureChannel 1 | Session 6378a196-2473-375e-ed2e-0250fdff8f98 created
[2020-09-15 13:14:03.346 (UTC-0700)] info/session   SecureChannel 1 | Session ns=1;g=6378a196-2473-375e-ed2e-0250fdff8f98 | Subscription 1 | Created the Subscription with a publishing interval of 500.00 ms
[2020-09-15 13:21:33.338 (UTC-0700)] info/channel   Connection 5 | SecureChannel 1 | SecureChannel renewed with a revised lifetime of 600.00s
[2020-09-15 13:29:03.344 (UTC-0700)] info/channel   Connection 5 | SecureChannel 1 | SecureChannel renewed with a revised lifetime of 600.00s
```

Comment: are you using the master or the 1.1 branch? the release page contains both.

Comment: My initial run was with master copied from the github link, but I just copied the 1.1 with the same results.

Comment: One thing I don't get. You said that you are using the single file release. The issue here: the examples are all built against the normal (non-amalgamation version). Can you help me there? Did you modify the example to fix the includes?

Comment: I didn't modify any of the includes. Just extracted the single file release, copied the example into that extracted directory and used the commands to build and run the server. I didn't see any complaints from the compile command and assumed all was okay. Perhaps that is the issue? Is it difficult to fix the includes for the single file release? I usually develop in Java and do not have as much experience with c/c++.

Comment: Is it possible that you have installed open62541 earlier at a system path? Either via "make; make install" or via a package manager?

The example can not possible compile against the single file release (see: the include list in tutorial_server_variable.c)

Comment: It could be, I might have built an older version of open62541 a few months ago when we were investigating how to integrate qtopcua.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Hint: if you would like to try the examples you must use the non-amalgamation version.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that you are connected to the right server application?

When I start the example mentioned I get the expected result. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure I have the right server instance because when I kill the process <ctrl-c> the subscriptions go red in the ua-expert client. The only other server I run on port 4840 has many variables in it. May I ask what platform and version of ua-expert you are testing with?

Comment: I am using both the (example server) and the UaExpert under Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). I am using version 1.5.1 of the UaExpert.

Comment: what happens if you right click on the object (address space pane) and select "rebrowse"

Comment: It re browses but the expected variables do not show up.